# How to access App.vue from another component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, components, vue-component

in my app written with VueJs 2, I have into the Vue.app this code:

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      title: 'Gestione fornitori',
      idfornitore: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    loadFunction (route) {
      this.$router.push(route)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I wish to access the property `idfornitore` from another component, I've used:

```
    mounted () {
      this.$parent.idfornitore = ''
    },
```

or also:

```
    mounted () {
      var Vue = require('vue')
      Vue.app.idfornitore = ''
    },
```

But it didn't worked. Which is the correct way to access the property from another component?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Use props to communicate data from parent to child.
- Emit events to communicate from child to parent

**Parent.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div>
         <h2>Parent: {{idfornitore}}</h2>
         <child :idfornitore="idfornitore" @changevalue="idfornitore = $event"></child>
         //idfornitore - data sent to child from parent.
         //changevalue - event emitted from child and received by parent
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Child from './compname.vue';

    export default {
        components:{
            "child" : Child
        },
        data(){
            return {
                idfornitore : "34"
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    Child: {{idfornitore}}
    <button @click="add()">Add</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
       props:["idfornitore"],
       methods : {
           add(){
               this.idfornitore++; // mutating props directly will result in vuejs warning. i have used this code here to show how this works.
               this.$emit("changevalue",this.idfornitore); //cascade the update to parent
           }
       }
    }
</script>
```

- if you feel communicating through props results in tight coupling, then the more convenient approach would be using eventBus

Comment: when there is multiple child and send data from last child to root main parent then it would be little complex. what would be the solution for that? I used Vuex to solve this.

Comment: if project is small, vuebus will be fine as i mentioned in my last point, vuex will be a overkill for small projects.

Comment: @Rahul  using props for communication would be the best approach for developing UI components like carousal,popup

Comment: Thank you, your code is explicative and I've understood how to operate.

Answer (score 2):

Communication between components are done via `props` or `events`.

If the component data you wish to access has child relationship, you could use `props`. But in your case, you need to change parent data. For this purpose, you could emit `events`. Events would be clean solution, if the component (you wish to update) is the direct parent of your current component.

If not so, use **EventBus** pattern. Using this pattern you could emit events from any component and listen to them in any other component and apply changes accordingly.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication
https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

EventBus patterns will produce really dirty codes and makes debugging really difficult if communication between components is needed more often.

To handle shared state between multiple components, it is highly recommended to use `vuex`. It makes your application state easily manageable and easy to maintain. I believe every real world Vue application needs state management and this could be easily achieved by `vuex` (or other similar tools) and I suggest you to do so.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html