# Change props value in vuejs2

Tags: modal-dialog, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new in vuejs2 development. I am working in a `modal` development. I kept the modal body code in a component and displaying that modal in another component. I have below code in modal body component.

```
<script>  
import SemanticModal from 'vue-ya-semantic-modal'

export default {        
    components: { SemanticModal: SemanticModal() },
    name: 'ModalBody',
    props: ['active1',],
    data() {
        return  {
            visible: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('sendValue', false);  //this is working
            this.visible = false
        },
        open () {
            this.visible = true
        },
    },
    watch: {
        active1 () {
            if (this.active1 && !this.visible) this.open()
            else if (!this.active1 && this.visible) this.close()
        },
    },
    directives: {
        'click-outside': {
            bind: function(el, binding, vNode) {
                el.onclick = function(e) {
                    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal");
                    el.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                        if (!modal[0].contains(event.target)) {                               
                       vNode.context.$emit('sendValue', false);  //this is not working
                       this.visible = false
                        } 
                    })            
               }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling that model (child) component in parent component like below

```
<modal-body :active1="active1" @sendValue="active1 = $event"></modal-body>
```

I need to change the below props `active1` value to false from child to parent component.

[image]

Comment: did you try this.$emit("sendValue",false); ?

Comment: Thanks @divine. I tried but it is not working.Thanks.

Comment: is the emitted value from child received by the parent?

Comment: Thanks @divine. May be received. I am receiving the value in parent using this line `<modal-body :active1="active1" @sendValue="active1 = $event"></modal-body>`. Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any warning or error messages in browser console? this thread may give you some ideas to fix your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48319821/4525120 . let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks @divine for your reply. I read your thread. But my issue is little different. I edited my post, look upon the comment inside `directive`. I would like to change the value of `props` of parent while clicking outside. Thanks.

Comment: after looking at your directive coding i feel like we could achieve the same behavior using @click .

Comment: Thanks @divine. Should I use `method` ? Should I place all the code in method ?

Comment: please check my answer. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling click event by using directives.

According to your requirement , `clickoutside` directive should emit `sendValue` event from `child to parent`. But i feel like your code has some complications.

***The proper code to accomplish your scenario is below***

```
          directives: {
                'clickoutside': {
                    bind: function(el, binding, vNode) {
                        el.onclick = function(e) {         
                            console.log("binding clicked");
                            vNode.context.$emit('sendValue', false);  
                        }
                    }    
                }
            }
```

if your objective is to use `click event` you can use `@click` binding to accomplish the same