# Vue js pass props from component tag in html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue component in the html and want to pass props to the js code and down to the vue component.

so in my html index.html

```
<div id="js-group-discounts">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker
      input-label="From">
    </datepicker>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker
      input-label="To">
    </datepicker>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in my js

```
  import Vue from "vue"
  import Datepicker from "../components/DatePicker"

  Vue.use(Datepicker)    
  new Vue({
   el: "#js-group-discounts",
   props: {
    inputLabel: {
     type: String,
  },
},
components: {
  Datepicker,
},
mount: {
  console.log(this.inputLabel) // returns undefinend
 },
})
```

This is the Datepicker child component

```
<template>
 <div >
    <label for="for">label</label>
    <input  type="text"
            class="form-control form-control-info"
            placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
            name="this.label"
            id="this.label"
            pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"
            required
            v-model="isInput"
            v-on:keyup="updateCalendar($event)"
            ref="startdate"
            @blur="blur"
            @focus="focus">
    <datepicker format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                id="start_calendar"
                input-class="form-control"
                placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"
                v-model="isPicker"
                :inline="true"
                v-show="isOpen"
                @mouseover.native="mouseOver"
                @selected="updateInput"></datepicker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 import Vue from "vue"
 import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker"
 Vue.use(Datepicker)

 export default {
    name: "datepicker",
    components: {
        Datepicker
    },

}
```

eventually i want to pass this down in the data to a child component but can't get passed this bit of passing the value from the html. Any help?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48319821/4525120

Comment: @divine they are setting the value in the js. I want to pass the value of the prop set in the html

Comment: all values should be stored in javascript objects. if you want to pass any values from parent to child you have to send the corresponding javascript object from parent to child.

Comment: So you can’t add a component to the html and have server side code set properties to pass down? This seems like something it should do. I find it hard to believe that this can’t be done.

Comment: you goal is to pass data from parent component to child component, am i correct?

Comment: If I understood correctly your problem is the same as in this link, right? https://forum.vuejs.org/t/passing-props-to-root-instances-in-2-0/244/5

Comment: @LassiUosukainen yes that looks the same, whats the best way to do this?

Comment: @LassiUosukainen actually not sure this is the same as i will have multiple instances of <datepicker> in the html with different values for props

Comment: `inputLabel` is a prop on the `<datepicker>` component, not the consuming parent. On a separate note, if there are multiple datepicker component, how should the parent know what value should `inputLabel` be?

Comment: Updated the code to give a better idea of what i'm doing.

Comment: @Adam Your VueJS instantiation code looks a bit off. `new Vue({...})` should contain a single argument which is an object.

Comment: just missing a closing bracket

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I figured that you want the consuming parent to have access to the `inputLabel` in the `<datepicker>` component. The parent usually does not have knowledge of the child's properties (remember that `inputLabel` is a property of the child component, **not that of the parent**).

In this case, you might want to use the following strategy:

- Use `vm.$emit` to emit a custom event, say `datepickermounted`, when the datepicker component is mounted. The consuming parent can then listen to this event using `v-on:datepickermounted` and receive data from the child component
- The `vm.$emit` can have a payload containing the unique ID of the component, and also the associated `inputLabel` of the component
- The parent has an array, say `datepickers`, that stores these emitted data. The parent listens onto the custom event, and upon receiving it, pushes it to its own data. Now the parent has access too all the `<datepicker>` child components' `inputLabel` :)

```js
var Datepicker = Vue.component('datepicker', {
  template: '#datepicker',
  props: {
    inputLabel: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // Let parent know that a new datepicker has been mounted
    this.$emit('datepickermounted', {
      id: this._uid,
      label: this.inputLabel
    });
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#js-group-discounts",
  data: {
    datepickers: []
  },
  components: {
    Datepicker
  },
  methods: {
    storeDatepickerLabel(payload) {
      this.datepickers.push(payload);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="js-group-discounts">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker input-label="datepickerLabel1" v-on:datepickermounted="storeDatepickerLabel"></datepicker>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker input-label="datepickerLabel2" v-on:datepickermounted="storeDatepickerLabel"></datepicker>
  </div>
  
  <hr />
  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(dp, index) in datepickers" :key="index">
      <strong>Datepicker id</strong>: {{ dp.id }}<br />
      <strong>Datepicker label</strong>: {{ dp.label }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="datepicker">
  <div class="dummy">
    I am a dummy datepicker component<br /> My label is {{this.inputLabel}}.
  </div>
</script>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `refs` to access the component, but be warned that `vm.$refs` are **not reactive** (e.g. if the `inputLabel` gets updated, you will not see it change!).

```js
var Datepicker = Vue.component('datepicker', {
  template: '#datepicker',
  props: {
    inputLabel: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#js-group-discounts",
  components: {
    Datepicker
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      console.log(this.$refs.datepicker1.inputLabel);
      console.log(this.$refs.datepicker2.inputLabel);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="js-group-discounts">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker input-label="datepickerLabel1" ref="datepicker1" ></datepicker>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker input-label="datepickerLabel2" ref="datepicker2" ></datepicker>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="datepicker">
  <div class="dummy">
    I am a dummy datepicker component<br /> My label is {{this.inputLabel}}.
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. seems like a long way of doing it, especially writing that loop out. no way of accessing this prop directly  <datepicker input-label="datepickerLabel1"?

Comment: @Adam Nope, but you can also use a `ref` :) not encouraged tho!

Comment: can you add standard html data attributes? <datepicker data-label="datepickerLabel1" , might just be better to do that and pass it down that way

Comment: @Adam I still don't know what "passing it down" means to you. To where do you want to pass the datepicker inputLabels to? p/s: See updated answer for use of `vm.$refs`

Comment: As a property of the component <datepicker> that is placed in the html. then pass that to the .js file, then pass that to the .vue file. i thought it was meant to be that direction root (html), parent (js), child (vue component)

Comment: i hold my head in my hands. ignore me i've figured it out from your answer.

Comment: @Adam running into this same problem. what conclusion did you reach?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var Datepicker = Vue.component('datepicker', {
  template: '#datepicker',
  props: {
    inputLabel: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#js-group-discounts",
  components: {
    Datepicker
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="js-group-discounts">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker input-label="datepickerLabel1"></datepicker>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <datepicker input-label="datepickerLabel2"></datepicker>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="datepicker">
  <div class="dummy">
    I am a dummy datepicker component<br /> My label is {{this.inputLabel}}.
  </div>
</script>
```