# call a function in a different vue component from v-for @click method

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, components

I am trying to use a method from on of my vue components in another vue component. I have implemented a solution below, however, I think there can be something more reusable.

Here is my problem: I want to call a method from one vue component (which is registered in the instance) in another component inside of it's template in a @click (or alternative) inside of a v-for.

This is my current solution:

**Vue Component 1** (this is the component making the call):

```
Vue.component('person-list', {
    props: ['user_id', 'token'],
    template: '<div>' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li v-for="person in persons" :data-id="person.lk_ID" 
class="someItems-list-item">{{ person.name }}</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>',
    data: function(){
        return {
            persons: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        //some code
    },
    mounted: function(){
        console.log('mounted list');
    }
});
```

**Vue Component 2**

```
var someItems= Vue.component('someItems-items-list', {
    props: ['g_id', 'token'],
    template: '<div>' +
    '<ul>' +
    '<li v-for="item in someItems">{{ item.name }}</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
    '</div>',
data: function(){
    return {
        someItems: null,
    }
},
methods: {
    callFunction: function (ID = null){
        this.$http.post('route', {someID: ID, _token: this.token}).then(function(response){
            this.someItems= response.body.items;
        });
    },
},
mounted: function(){
    this.callFunction();
}
});
```

**Instance**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'someItems-items-list': someItems,
    },
});
```

**Solution in Jquery**

```
$(document).on('click','.someItems-list-item',function () {
   app.$refs.someItems.callFunction($(this).data('id'));
});
```

This solution works fine, and its not that much more code, but I think it would be cleaner and easier to maintain if I could call callFunction() like this:

**Vue Component 1**

```
template: '<div>' +
        '<ul>' +
        '<li v-for="person in persons" @click="app.$refs.someItems.callFunction(person.lk_ID)">{{ person.name }}</li>' +
        '</ul>' +
        '</div>',
```

However, when I try that, it says that app is undefined. I have also tried the above with this:

**Vue Component 1**

```
return {
        //other code,
        this.someItems: someItems,
    }
```

And then calling in `@click="someItems.callFunction(1)"` but it also does not work. All these components are inside of app.js. I am working with laravel,vue,jquery.

I feel that I may be missing something in terms of how to connect two vue components to each other, and have been unable to learn it from searching.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48355980/3226121) could help you out

Comment: Also, `@click="app.$refs.someItems...`, should be `$refs.someItems...`

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to approach this in Vue is with emitting custom events or vuex. Seems like you're looking for the custom event approach. With this method, you would emit a custom event with a payload from component A, listen to that event in the parent component, and then update the prop of component B, and setup a watch in component B that would respond when the prop changes and call a method.

This article explains it well:

https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-emit-data-in-vue-beyond-the-vuejs-documentation

The most important parts are:

```
//emit from component A
this.$emit('update-cart', item)

//setup listener in parent
<componentA @update-cart="updateCart">
updateCart(e) {
    this.cart.push(e);
    this.total = this.shoppingCartTotal;
  },

//setup componentB with prop from parent
<componentB :total="total">

//have watch in componentB
props: ['total'],
watch:{
  total:function(val){
    //call fn with new val
  }
}
```